# Sum specific columns using loop

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

I have a table that looks like this: (Note: this is just a partial table, my real table has several more columns of qresult_# and trial_#)

```
Contract    FA     NAAR    q    trial_1   qresult_1    trial_2    qresult_2 
CM300      9746    47000  0.5    0.4352      d          0.7534        l
UL350     80000      0    0.01   0.9287      l          0.2336        l
RAD34     50000    10000  0.943  0.6161      d          0.1545        d
```

The table is calculated using a for loop, so that the columns trial_i and qresult_i are created for as many columns as I wish. This is the code used to create the table:

```
testdata <- data.frame(Contract = as.character(c("CM300","UL350","RAD34")),
                  FA = as.numeric(as.character(c("9746","80000","50000"))),
                  NAAR = as.numeric(as.character(c("47000","0","10000"))),
                  q = as.numeric(as.character(c("0.50","0.01","0.943"))))

trialmax <- 2
for(i in 1:trialmax){
   trial <- runif(3, min = 0, max = 1)
   testdata[ , paste0("trial_", i)] <- trial
   testdata[ , paste0("qresult_", i)] <- ifelse(trial >= testdata$q, "l", "d")
}
```

Here is my question: I would like to sum the FA column and the NAAR column for all contracts labeled 'd', and all contracts labeled 'l' for each trial individually. So for trial_1, the FA for 'd' would be 59746 and NAAR for 'd' would be 57000, the FA for 'l' would be 80000 and the NAAR for 'l' would be 0. And repeat this for each trial. The end result would be four values for each trial.

I haven't found a code that allows me to run it successfully. I would like the expected output to be four values for each trial. Perhaps look something like this, repeated for each trial:

```
trial1_d_fa <- if(trial_1 = 'd') {sum(testdata$FA)}
trial1_l_fa <- if(trial_1 = 'l') {sum (testdata$FA)}
trial1_d_naar <- if(trial_1 = 'd') {sum(testdata$NAAR)}
trial1_l_naar <- if(trial_1 = 'l') {sum(testdata$NAAR)}
```

I am struggling with getting a for loop to work, since the column name in the code is defined using i. I am new to R, so any tips are greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: Update**

The code suggested by bouncyball below worked on my test data, but when I used it on my real data, I got the following error message:

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :
names do not match previous names
```

Looking through this website, I can see it is an issue with the `rbind()` function. I have tried converting the column names to match my data, but I continue to get the same error.

Here is the beginning of my dataset `head(data)`. Any advice is appreciated!

```
Contract    FA     NAAR      q      trial_1    qresult_1    trial_2    qresult_2    
CM20002U  10000   4902.34   0.0255   0.7921        l        0.5182       l
CM20051U  45700   28788.81  0.0121   0.0083        d        0.0707       l
CM20076U  50000   20824.54  0.1054   0.5616        l        0.0915       d
```

Comment: Can u show the expected output

Comment: I have edited my original post to show this and where I have gotten stuck. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using `lapply` and `by` functions. We need to repeat the call to `do.call('rbind', ...)` because there are two entries in the list resulting from `lapply`:

```
trial_max <- 2

do.call('rbind', 
        do.call('rbind', 
                lapply(paste0('qresult_', 1:trial_max), function(q){
                  by(testdata, testdata[,q], FUN = function(d) 
                    data.frame('id' = q, 
                               'val' = unique(d[,q]), 
                               'sum_FA' = sum(d$FA),
                               'sum_NAAR' = sum(d$NAAR),
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
})))

         id val sum_FA sum_NAAR
1 qresult_1   d  59746    57000
2 qresult_2   d  59746    57000
3 qresult_1   l  80000        0
4 qresult_2   l  80000        0
```

Using `lapply`, we iterate over the `qresult_i` columns, then we use the `by` function to apply a function to `testdata` split by the values in the respective `qresult_i` columns. Finally, we store the results in a `data.frame`.

The results are stored in a `data.frame`, which should make it easy to subset and get the values you're interested in.

Comment: Is there a way to do this when I have many more than just 2 trials? I am hoping to run this with hundreds of trials, and so typing each qresult column name by hand would be quite tedious.

Comment: Will each column be named consistently? E.g. `qresult_1`, `qresult_2`, ..., `qresult_n`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The columns are named trial_1, qresult_1, trial_2, qresult_2, trial_3, qresult_3, etc...

Comment: using `paste0('qresult_', 1:max_trials)`, you can avoid that extra typing. I edited my answer to show this

Comment: When I tried to apply this to the larger data set imported from excel, I got this error message: 'Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names'

I tried checking all of the column names, but everything appears to be identical. Do you have any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: @Karly is there a way for you to post a sample of your data, e.g. `dput(head(your_data))`?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this website, and do not know how to do that. The code you suggested yesterday worked with my sample data, but when I applied it to the entire data set (a table with 58000 rows and 20 columns), I got the following error message: `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names`.

By looking at other questions on this website, I can see that this error is caused with the `rbind()` function when the column names in two data sets do not line up. I have tried to fix it by manually changing the names, but I continue to get this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can edit your original question and post the output of running `dput(head(your_data))` in R. `your_data` is replaced by whatever name you've used for your `data.frame`. Without seeing your actual data, I'm not sure why that would be happening

Comment: I have edited my question to include my actual data. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: @Karly does my solution fail on the actual data you just posted? It works on my machine

Comment: I continue to get the error `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names`. Do you know what names this error is referring to?